# Geometric sequence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine the value(s) of k, so that the positive numbers

$\log_8(k-1)$, $3\log_8(k-1)$ and $6$

form a geometric sequence (in order given above).

Comment: Think about the condition for three numbers to form a geometric sequence. Then put this into an equation and solve for $k$.

Comment: Hint: Notice that the middle term is 3 times the first term. Then notice that the third term is 6.

Comment: Answer is to be 5. However my calculations are not getting 5 as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, we have three terms $\log_8(k-1), 3\log_8(k-1)$ & $6$ are in G.P. then we have 
$$(3\log_8(k-1))^2=6\times \log_8(k-1)$$
$$(\log_2(k-1))^2=2\log_2(k-1)$$
$$(\log_2(k-1))^2-2\log_2(k-1)=0$$
$$\log_2(k-1)[\log_2(k-1)-2]=0$$
$$\iff \log_2(k-1)=0\iff k-1=2^0=1$$ $$k=1+1=2$$

or $$\log_2(k-1)-2=0\iff k-1=2^2=4$$
$$k=4+1=5$$
but the numbers are positive hence, $k=2$ is not acceptable hence, we have

$$\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{\color{blue}{k=5}}$$

Comment: How did you change base form log_8 to log_2?

Comment: Alright, Notice the formula $$\log_{a^m}(b)=\frac{1}{m}\log_{a}(b)$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $m=\log_8 (k-1)$, i.e. $k=8^m+1$.

Sequence becomes $$m, 3m, 6$$.

As this is a GP, $$6=9m\\
m=\frac23\\
\therefore k=8^{\frac23}+1=4+1
=5\qquad\blacksquare$$

(Note that "$\log$" only appears once :))

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the equation
$$\frac{3\log[8(k+1)]}{\log[8(k+1)]}=\frac6{3\log[8(k+1)]}$$

What is the problem with it?